# How to register shapes in a Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I am making a program where the Turtle utilizes a Tkinter Canvas to draw on (RawTurtle(tkinter.canvas)). I want to change the shape of the turtle (with a .gif image).

I tried the functions with turtlescreen() provided with the documentation on this but tkinter.Canvas doesn't have a register_shape or addshape method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code that does what you describe:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.register_shape("test.gif")

turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
turtle.shape("test.gif")

# body of code here ...

screen.mainloop()
```

Perhaps you got one of the steps out of order?  Also, the turtle library provides `ScrolledCanvas` as an alternative to `Canvas`.